# get values as array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql=mysql_query("select cost from projectdetails");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $data=$row['cost'];
}
```

This is my php code Can you help me how to get like this,,

```
$data = array("0" => 898, "1" => 1498, "2" => 1343,"3" => 1345, "4" => 1045, "5" => 1343, "6" => 987);
```

Comment: is your problem to create an array()? to use an array() or what i guess, you don't know what your code does

Answer (score 1):

Just `$data[] = $row['cost'];` and you'll get `$data` as an array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$count = 0;
$sql=mysql_query("select cost from projectdetails"); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))     { 
    $data[$count]=$row['cost']; 
    $count++; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use PDO, its much better, try this

```
//edit for your server/database
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "hostname";
$dbname = "database-name";

//to connect to the database
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=utf8', $username, $password);
```

Then the query is very simple

```
$query = "SELECT cost FROM projectdetails;";
$sth = $db->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();

$data = $sth->fetchAll();
```

And now you have all your $data as an array, you can loop through it, assign different values or whatever you want.